# react-query: How to process a queue, one item at a time, and remove the original data after processing?

Tags: react-query

I'm using [react-query 4](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/) to get some data from my server via JSON:API and create some objects:

```
export type QueryReturnQueue = QueueObject[] | false;

const getQueryQueue = async (query: string): Promise<QueryReturnQueue> => {
  const data = await fetchAuth(query);
  const returnData = [] as QueueObject[];
  if (data) {
    data.map((queueItem) => returnData.push(new QueueObject(queueItem)));
    return returnData;
  }
  return false;
};

function useMyQueue(
  queueType: QueueType,
): UseQueryResult<QueryReturnQueue, Error> {
  const queryKey =  ['getQueue', queueType];
  return useQuery<QueryReturnQueue, Error>(
    queryKey,
    async () => {
      const query = getUrl(queueType);
      return getQueryQueue(query);
    },
  );
}
```

Then I have a component that displays the objects one at a time and the user is asked to make a choice (for example, "swipe left" or "swipe right").  This queue only goes in one direction-- the user sees a queueObject, processes the object, and then goes to the next one.  The user cannot go back to a previous object, and the user cannot skip ahead.

So far, I've been using `useContext()` to track the index in the queue as state.  However, I've been running into several bugs with this when the queue gets refreshed, which happens a lot, so I thought it would be easier to directly manipulate the data returned by `useQuery()`.

How can I remove items as they are processed from the locally cached query results?

My current flow:

- Fetch the queue data and generation objects with `useQuery()`.
- Display the queue objects one at a time using `useContext()`.
- Mutate the displayed object with `useMutation()` to modify `useContext()` and then show the next object in the cached data from `useQuery()`.

My desired flow:

- Fetch the queue data and generation objects with `useQuery()`.
- Mutate the displayed object with `useMutation()`, somehow removing the mutated item from the cached data from `useQuery()` (like what `shift()` does for arrays).

Sources I consulted

- [Best practices for editing data after useQuery call](https://github.com/TanStack/query/discussions/530) (couldn't find an answer relevant to my case)
- [Optimistic updates](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/optimistic-updates) (don't know how to apply it to my case)

Comment: I don't find the question very clear, but it sounds like you should look into `queryClient.setQueryData` (https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/reference/QueryClient#queryclientsetquerydata) to shift the first item from the list + only ever display the first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Jakub Kotrs:

> shift the first item from the list + only ever display the first

I was able to implement this in my `useMutation()` hook:

```
  onMutate: async (queueObjectRemoved) => {
    const queryKey =  ['getQueue', queueType];

    // Cancel any outgoing refetches
    // (so they don't overwrite our optimistic update).
    await queryClient.cancelQueries({
      queryKey,
    });

    if (data?.[0]?.id === queueObjectRemvoed.data.id) {
      // Optimistically update the data by removing the first item.
      data.shift();
      queryClient.setQueryData(queryKey, () => data);
    } else {
      throw new Error('Unable to set queue!');
    }
  },
  onError: () => {
    const queryKey =  ['getQueue', queueType];
    setShowErrorToast(true);
    queryClient.invalidateQueries(
      queryKey,
    );
  },
```

This way users can process all the items in the current queue before needing to refetch.

Answer (score 0):

> My desired flow:
>
> Fetch the queue data and generation objects with useQuery().
> Mutate the displayed object with useMutation(), somehow removing the mutated item from the cached data from useQuery() (like what shift() does for arrays).

This is the correct way to think about the data flow. But mutations shouldn't be updating the cache with data, they should be invalidating existing cache data.

You have defined your query correctly. Now you simply have to instruct your mutation function (which should be making an API call that updates the records queue) to `invalidate` all existing queries for the data in the `onSuccess` handler.

e.g.

```js
function useMyMutation(recordId, queueType) {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  return useMutation({
    mutationFn: ({id, swipeDirection}) => 
                   asyncAPICall(`/swipes/${id}`, { swipeDirection }),
    onSuccess: () => queryClient.invalidateQueries(['getQueue', queueType]);

  });
}
```

Comment: "But mutations shouldn't be updating the cache with data, they should be invalidating existing cache data." That's not true, there is an entire chapter of "optimistic updates" missing in that sentence. ;) See https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/updates-from-mutation-responses + https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/optimistic-updates

Comment: optimistic updates are fine, but (IMO) not needed for most situations and makes managing the state of your cache a lot more complicated. Unless you know you need that complexity for some other feature you can probably skip it.